# Batch only certain words for variable allowed

Tags: batch-file

Evening, I'm trying to make a list of several words that can be set as a variable inside a batch script.

For example:

```
set allowedvar=James
set secondallowedwar=Jane

if not %allowedvar% == James or John or Smith ( echo Not correct variable set for allowedvar )
if not %secondallowedwar% == Jane or Jennifer or Allice ( echo Not correct variable set for secondallowedwar )
```

So in this case, `allowedvar` can only be set as `James`, `John` or `Smith` and `secondallowedwar` can only be set as `Jane`, `Jennifer` or `Allice`

How can I make this possible inside batch script?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set allowedValues=/James/John/Smith/
set /P allowedVar=Enter the name: 
if "!allowedValues:/%allowedVar%/=!" neq "%allowedValues%" (
   echo The name is valid
) else (
   echo Name NOT valid
)
```

**EDIT**: *Case sensitive version added*

The solution above is case insensitive. For a case-sensitive one, use this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set allowedValues=/James/John/Smith/
set /P allowedVar=Enter the name: 
if "!allowedValues:/%allowedVar%/=!" neq "%allowedValues%" (
   echo Name matchs case insensitive
   if "!allowedValues:/%allowedVar%/=/%allowedVar%/!" equ "%allowedValues%" (
      echo Name matchs case sensitive
   )
) else (
   echo Name NOT matchs
)
```

Comment: is it case-sensitive? If not, can I make it be?

Comment: @JohnWaynejr.: See the new version above.

Answer (score 1):

It is easily doable like this:

```
rem allowed values, separated with spaces:
set allowed=James John Smith
for %%i in (%allowed%) do if "%1"=="%%i" goto ok
echo Invalid value: %1    
goto :eof

:ok
echo You picked: %1
```

This script uses the first command line argument (`%1`) as the variable to test, but you can use anything you want in its place.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say the best way of doing it as it depends on the rest of your script and how it's working, but something like this should work:

```
IF %allowedvar%==James GOTO correctvar
IF %allowedvar%==John GOTO correctvar
IF %allowedvar%==Smith GOTO correctvar
::The following line will only run if none of the above IF statements succeeded
echo Incorrect variable value && pause && goto start

:correctvar
echo Hello %allowedvar%! Nice to see you!
```